# Creating and filling a ROOT file from a text file

Tags: c++, tree, root-framework

this is about C++ coding in CERN ROOT.
So I have a text file with columns of data. Now I need to make a .root file with all the data in a tree. How would I do this? Also, if the text file has column headers, how would I write my code to get them to be my tree's branch names?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this example from the ROOT web page shows how to do exactly what you want:

http://root.cern.ch/root/html534/tutorials/tree/cernbuild.C.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a `TTree` method for that: http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html#TTree:ReadFile

To use the reader as branch names you have to be a bit more creative. Read the line, parse it and use it as a branch descriptor in the `TTree:ReadFile` call.